# Dynamic open graph in react

Tags: reactjs, metadata, meta-tags, share-open-graph

This is a dynamic page in my website: [link](https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/%D7%90%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95_-_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-VRN)

I gave this page all this code as meta tags for dynamic favicon, dynamic title, dynamic description and most important **dynamic open graph (og:image for example) when sharing in Whatsapp, Facebook etc.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import Favicon from 'react-favicon';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

export default function MetaData(props) {
    const [meta] = useState({
        name: props.name,
        description: props.description,
        ogUrl: props.ogUrl,
        imgUrl: "https://bucard.co.il/server/public/images/uploads/1601487360190-meat-shop-logo_71835-89.jpg"
    });
    
    return (
        <>
            <MetaTags>
                <meta name="title" content={`Digital Card Of ${meta.name}`} />
                <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={meta.description}
                />

                <meta property="og:title" content={`Digital Card Of ${meta.name}`} />
                {meta.imgUrl && <meta property="og:image" content={meta.imgUrl} />}
                <meta
                    property="og:description"
                    content={meta.description}
                />
                <meta property="og:url" content={meta.ogUrl} />
            </MetaTags>
            <Helmet>
                <title>{`Digital Card Of ${meta.name}`}</title>
                {meta.imgUrl && <link rel="icon" href={meta.imgUrl}></link>}
                <meta name="title" content={`Digital Card Of ${meta.name}`} />
                <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={meta.description}
                />
                <meta property="og:title" content={`Digital Card Of ${meta.name}`} />
                {meta.imgUrl && <meta property="og:image" content={meta.imgUrl} />}
                <meta
                    property="og:description"
                    content={meta.description}
                />
                <meta property="og:url" content={meta.ogUrl} />
            </Helmet>
            {meta.imgUrl && <Favicon url={meta.imgUrl} />}
        </>
    );
}
```

Now, if you enter the link to the page above, by f12 you can see that the og:image in the head section is just right -

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://bucard.co.il/server/public/images/uploads/1601487360190-meat-shop-logo_71835-89.jpg">
```

, but when sharing the page on Whasapp for example, that image not showing, and instead the website favicon is rendered.

[Snapshot of the rendered image when sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcMMs.png)

Any help please ? I just need the og:image to work :)

Comment: You'll probably need to code your `og:image` tag directly into the `index.html` file in your reactjs project folder.  Since ReactJS is JS, it's client-rendered, and servers often don't render JS in generating previews.  Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I can't code it directly to index.html because this image is very dynamic, and I have lot of page and the user can change this image, so it should be coded in the comonent.

Comment: It doesn't look like whatsapp supports it.  Whatsapp would have to change their code to support it.  Not sure anything can be done?  LinkedIn and Facebook support it.